# Value returns 0/0 in this program

Tags: python, function, scope, return-value, fractions

So I wrote a python code to add two fractions. The code is running smoothly without any runtime or compile time errors. But the biggest problem is the output returns as `0/0`. What part of the code should I change to get the sum of two fractions as output?

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if(a == 0):
        return b
    return gcd(b % a, a)

def smallest(n3, den3):
    common = gcd(n3, den3)
    n3 = n3 // common
    den3 = den3 // common
    return n3, den3

def add_fraction(n1, den1, n2, den2, n3, den3):
    den3 = gcd(den1, den2)
    den3 = (den1 * den2) // den3
    n3 = n1 * (den3 // den1) + n2 * (den2 // den1)
    smallest(den3, n3)

n1, den1, n2, den2 = map(int, input().split())
n3 = 0
den3 = 0
add_fraction(n1, den1, n2, den2, n3, den3)
print("{num1}/{denom1} + {num2}/{denom2} = {num3}/{denom3}".format(
    num1=n1, denom1=den1, num2=n2, denom2=den2, num3=n3, denom3=den3
))
```

Comment: Don't use `input` in a [mcve]. Show a sample run with `n1,den1,n2,den2 = <sequence of 4 concrete numbers that illustrate the issue>`

Comment: Also, you're not returning anything from the last function. Names are bound locally and integers are immutable. In other words, you won't see changes outside the function except by returning a value

Answer (score 2):

### `return`ing a value from a function

Your confusion comes from the way variables and function parameters behave in python. When you write `den3 = (den1*den2)//den3` and `n3 = n1*(den3//den1) + n2*(den2//den1)`, you are not modifying any variables outside of the function; you are only reassigning locally the name `den3` and the name `n3` to a new value.

Instead, you can use the `return` keyword to return values from the function:

```py
def add_fraction(n1,den1,n2,den2):
    den3 = gcd(den1,den2)
    den3 = (den1*den2)//den3
    n3 = n1*(den3//den1) + n2*(den2//den1)
    (n3, den3) = smallest(n3,den3)
    return (n3, den3)

n1,den1,n2,den2 = map(int,input().split())
n3, den3 = add_fraction(n1, den1, n2, den2)
print("{num1}/{denom1} + {num2}/{denom2} = {num3}/{denom3}".format(num1=n1,denom1=den1,num2=n2,denom2=den2,num3=n3,denom3=den3))
```

### fixing the math

You have already written a function `smallest` which simplifies a fraction with the use of `gcd`. Hence, you no longer need to call `gcd` inside `add_fraction`: just compute a non-simplified addition of the two fractions, then call `smallest` on the result. You can use the following equation:

```
n1 / den1 + n2 / den2 = (n1 * den2 + den1 * n2) / (den1 * den2)
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a couple of seconds :)

Comment: Sadly it prints `3/4 + 1/3 = 4/3` :'(

Comment: I think I beat you to the math fix though :)

Comment: Have a +1 either way.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be under the impression that by passing an integer to a function, you can fill the value of that integer somehow. That does not work in python. An integer object is immutable. When you do `den3 = blah`, a new `int` object is bound to the **local** name `den3`, but the one in the global scope outside the function keeps pointing to the original `int` of `0`.

Python does not normally use function arguments for output at all because of this. So for example, you would rewrite `add_fraction` like this:

```
def add_fraction(n1, den1, n2, den2):
    den3 = gcd(den1, den2)
    den3 = (den1 * den2) // den3
    n3 = n1 * (den3 // den1) + n2 * (den2 // den1)
    return smallest(den3, n3)
```

Your calling code would then become

```
n1, den1, n2, den2 = map(int,input().split())
n3, den3 = add_fraction(n1, den1, n2, den2)
```

This will fix the immediate issue the question is about, and show you how to use python functions properly. It will not fix the math error that tells me that `1/2 + 3/4 = 1/2`. Specifically, the numerator in `add_fraction` should be computed as

```
n3 = n1 * (den3 // den1) + n2 * (den3 // den2)
```

(your second term reads `n2 * (den2 // den1)` for some reason). And of course the return value needs to respect the order of the parameters to `smallest`, which are currently reversed:

```
return smallest(n3, den3)
```

As a final point, as long as you're using python 3.6+, you may consider using f-strings for the final output:

```
print(f"{n1}/{den1} + {n2}/{den2} = {n3}/{den3}")
```

By placing an `f` in front of your string, any format specs in curly braces will be replaced by the corresponding names from the local namespace. Any accessible names will be used, including global and built-in. In fact, you can evaluate simple expressions too.